# Editing file into android application's resources

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop an application for android...
The question is, I need to Edit or create(if not existing already) an XML file in the Resources folder or Assets folder(anyone will do)...How can I do that?

I can get the XML file to open from the Assets folder using the
    `getAssets()`.
But I need to modify its contents and store it again somewhere....
I don't want to save it on the memory card....Please Help...

I hope you guys will do....Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

> The question is, I need to Edit or create(if not existing already) an XML file in the Resources folder or Assets folder(anyone will do)...How can I do that?

You don't. Assets and resources are read-only at runtime.

> But I need to modify its contents and store it again somewhere

Store it in a file using Java file I/O.